# Performing multiple linear regression on SPSS when there are many predictor variables

Tags: regression, spss

I have a question about performing multiple linear regression preferably on SPSS 27.

I had 3 dependent variables on the teacher's intention to remain on the job. I got a mean of the scores (measured in a 7-point Likert Scale) for dependent variables. But I am stuck especially with regards to performing the regression as I've 25 predictor/ independent variables. I watched some YouTube videos but did not help me much. I would appreciate it if somebody could explain to me, in detail, how I could go ahead with the performance. I am mostly self-taught and do not have a go-to person, so any kind of help here online, in a simple, detailed manner, would help me learn. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: How many observations do you have? What's the problem with 25 predictors?

Comment: I've 133 observations. I've not done much multiple linear regression. So would appreciate it if you could tell me what stepts I could do on SPSS 27. ty

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking concrete steps, but just in case you are, in order to perform multiple linear regression in SPSS, you go to Analyze...Regression...Linear and then put your dependent into the "Dependent" box and all your predictors into "independent(s)" box and click OK. As for the nr of predictors, a common rule of thumb you see is that you'd need at least 10-20 observations per parameter estimated, which would mean you have too many predictors for your sample size. That's not an absolute rule but you may want to consider trying to cut your predictors e.g. via factor analysis.